# jsFiddle toggle JavaScript and CSS panels?

Tags: jsfiddle

Is there a way to toggle JavaScript and CSS panels?

Comment: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/) has this feature. I use it every day.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this isn't a feature of [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

According to their keyboard shortcuts you can only toggle the sidebar (<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>).

Comment: and FYI that is CTRL+SHIFT+UP Arrow, can not tell you how many different keys I tried.

Comment: I normally just resize the html and css panels, and now I know how to toggle the only one that can not be resized I am sorted.

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't work on Macs as the same keyboard is a system shortcut...